# HP-UFT / VBscript - Setting an array value through a function with an array index reference

Tags: vbscript, hp-uft

I have an issue with assigning/retrieving correct values to/from an array which is within a class in VBScript. Whenever I try to set the array's value through a stand-alone function, it just does not work and I keep getting the old array values.
Here is an example code:

```
Class NewClass

    Public TestValues

    Public Sub Init()
        TestValues = array("value0", "value1", "value2")
    End Sub
End Class

Class NewFunctions

    Public Function GetValue(xRef)
        GetValue = xRef(2)
        print "Value within Function: " & xRef(2)
    End Function

    Public Sub SetValue(xRef, xValue)
        xRef(2) = xValue
        print "Value within Sub: " & xRef(2)
    End Sub
End Class

Dim MyClass, MyFunction
Set MyClass = New NewClass
Set MyFunction = New NewFunctions
```

Now, when I try to set the **index 2** of the given array **MyClass.TestValues** with the **SetValue** Sub, it claims the new value has been set, but when I then call **GetValue** for this array or print out the content of the **MyClass.TestValues(2)** directly, I am still getting the old values:

```
MyFunction.SetValue MyClass.TestValues, "newvalue2"
```

It returns: *Value within Sub: newvalue2*



But when I retrieve the value with GetValue:

```
 MyFunction.GetValue MyClass.TestValues
```

It returns: *Value within Function: value2*, which is the old value.



When I, however, set the array directly:

```
Myclass.TestValues(2) = "newvalue2"
```

then calling with:

```
MyFunction.GetValue MyClass.TestValues
```

gives me correct result: *Value within Function: newvalue2*


I am not sure whether this is a general VBScript behavior and I am making a mistake in hoping to change array values in this 'dirty' manner or whether this is strictly HP-UFT (Unified Functional Testing) related, since this is where I could observe this.
I am not a profficient VBScripter either so I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101(v=vs.84).aspx) behaviour

> **Argument in a Class**
>
> If the parameter is specified as ByRef, the argument is passed by
>   value if the variable sent as an argument is in a class

Comment: Thank you for the response. What would then be the proper way to set the array value (on index 2) with the **MyFunction.Setvalue** ?

Comment: @JoeyJoe, if `xRef` is not needed to be an array, modify `NewFunctions.SetValue` not to expect an array but an object reference and call a method on this object to change their inner state.  If you can not do that, change how the property `NewClass.TestValues` is exposed, wrapping it in an object that imitates the behaviour of an array.